# What is this shrub with large heads composed of single flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

I can't identify this flower that has been previously here in the garden since I have moved. Here's a photo.

[image].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Red Hydrangea macrophylla](https://www.google.com/search?q=hydrangea%20macrophylla%20red%20beauty&espv=2&biw=1455&bih=726&site=webhp&tbm=isch&imgil=akE3dHJx8cHfhM%253A%253BUV4Ha3dH9PDUgM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.esveld.nl%25252Fhtmldiaen%25252Fh%25252Fhymrbe.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=akE3dHJx8cHfhM%253A%252CUV4Ha3dH9PDUgM%252C_&usg=__fRC0AcWSBzLop_ldUvhmL3mshsg%3Dhttp://)

Here we go...you lucky person!!!

Comment: You have to learn to dry these flowers!  I've never dried the red hydrangeas but one Christmas all I used was dried hydrangea, blue and purple and green and the tree was breathtaking.  Just stick the stems in the tree.  The best way is cutting the flowers while they are beautiful and putting the stems in a little bit of water.